# ¿como hacer funcionar la resta?

Tags: java

Se introduce un saldo, luego se le suma un ingreso que es por teclado. Esto anda bien, pero cuando se realiza la resta, termina restando el saldo introducido pero sin la suma, por ejemplo:

- *intro: 100*
- *ingreso: 20*
- *suma: 120*
- *resta: 20*
- *saldo total: -80*

---

```
    public class ClienteService {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    public Cliente ClienteService() {
    Cliente login = new Cliente(); //el contructor vacio
    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de cuenta");
    login.setNumeroCuenta(leer.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Ingrese su DNI");
    login.setDni(leer.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Ingrese su saldo actual");
    login.setSaldoActual(leer.nextInt());
    return login; 
}
public void  ingreso(Cliente login) {
    System.out.println("Ingresar una cantidad de dinero");
    double ingreso = leer.nextDouble();
    double suma = ingreso + login.getSaldoActual();
    System.out.println("Se suma el dinero ingresado al Saldo actual : " + suma);
}
public void Retirar(Cliente login ) {

    System.out.println("Retirar una cantidad de dinero");
    double retiro = leer.nextDouble();

    double resta = retiro - login.getSaldoActual();
    System.out.println("Se resta  al Saldo actual  : " + resta);
}
```

Comment: prueba con `double resta = login.getSaldoActual() - retiro;`

Comment: @DiegoDscz es importante usar el getter login.setSaldoActual() para actualizar el valor de la suma, revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: Dale buenísimo, si no llego a revisarlo hoy porque en un rato me.voy al trabajo, lo reviso hoy a la noche
 Ni bien tenga algo te escribo. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En el método `ingreso()` cuando obtienes la suma, debes definirla como el nuevo valor del saldo actual usando el setter `login.setSaldoActual(..)` :

```
...
double suma = ingreso + login.getSaldoActual();
login.setSaldoActual((int)suma);
...
```

En el método `Retirar()` al valor mayor que es el saldoActual y restar a este el retiro que sería el valor menor.

```
...
//double resta = retiro - login.getSaldoActual(); 
double resta = login.getSaldoActual() - retiro;
...
```

El código resultante sería:

```
public class ClienteService {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Cliente ClienteService() {
        Cliente login = new Cliente(); //el contructor vacio
        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de cuenta");
        login.setNumeroCuenta(leer.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Ingrese su DNI");
        login.setDni(leer.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Ingrese su saldo actual");
        login.setSaldoActual(leer.nextInt());
        return login;
    }

    public void ingreso(Cliente login) {
        System.out.println("Ingresar una cantidad de dinero");
        double ingreso = leer.nextDouble();
        double suma = ingreso + login.getSaldoActual();
        System.out.println("Se suma el dinero ingresado al Saldo actual : " + suma);
        //Actualiza saldo actual.
        login.setSaldoActual((int)suma);
    }

    public void Retirar(Cliente login) {
        System.out.println("Retirar una cantidad de dinero");
        double retiro = leer.nextDouble();
        double resta = login.getSaldoActual() - retiro;
        System.out.println("Se resta  al Saldo actual  : " + resta);
        //Actualiza saldo actual.
        login.setSaldoActual((int)resta);
    }
}
```

---

Ejemplo:

```
Ingrese su saldo actual
100
Ingresar una cantidad de dinero
20
Se suma el dinero ingresado al Saldo actual : 120.0
Retirar una cantidad de dinero
20
Se resta  al Saldo actual  : 100.0
```

Comment: Hola la resta daria 100. Es decir 120 - 20.

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta, el problema principal es que debes actualizar el valor del saldo actual usando el getter login.setSaldoActual( ); , y también a partir del saldo actual restar el retiro en el  método Retirar() ,  lo mismo para el método ingreso() @DiegoDscz

Comment: Hola al final se resolvio de esta manera:

Comment: public void  ingreso(Cliente login) {
        System.out.println("Ingresar una cantidad de dinero");
        double ingreso = leer.nextDouble();
        login.setSaldoActual(ingreso + login.getSaldoActual());
        System.out.println("Se suma el dinero ingresado al Saldo actual : " + login.getSaldoActual());
    }

Comment: public void Retirar(Cliente login ) { //double suma = ingreso + login.getSaldoActual();
        System.out.println("Retirar una cantidad de dinero");
        double retiro = leer.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Se resta  al Saldo actual  : " + Math.abs(retiro - login.getSaldoActual()));   // cuenta.setSaldo(cuenta.getSaldo() - retiro);
    }

Comment: Igualmente, mil gracias por todo

Answer (score 1):

En tu metod ingreso vos estas creando una variable suma la cual acumula el ingreso obtenido + el saldo ingresado. pero en que momento estableces que suma sera el nuevo saldo del usuario???

```
public void  ingreso(Cliente login) {
    System.out.println("Ingresar una cantidad de dinero");
    double ingreso = leer.nextDouble();
    double suma = ingreso + login.getSaldoActual();
    System.out.println("Se suma el dinero ingresado al Saldo actual : " + suma);
}
```

lo que faltaria agregarle a tu metodo es lo siguiente:

```
login.setSaldoActual(suma);
```

ahora en tu metodo retirar no tiene sentido que el retiro sea mayor que el saldoActual ??? seria al reves a tu saldoActual le vas a descontar el retiro

```
double resta = login.getSaldoActual()-retiro;
```

y si vas a continuar descontando no te olvides de establecer el nuevo saldo

```
login.setSaldoActual(resta);
```

Comment: Gracias por la referencia, se pudo solucionar como mostre en uno de los comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

Con tu código pude reproducir el error.
Encuentro dos errores, el primero es que en:

```
double resta = retiro - login.getSaldoActual();
```

Debes calcular el nuevo saldo así:

```
double resta = login.getSaldoActual() - retiro;
```

El segundo error es que no estás cambiando realmente el saldo del cliente en ningún lugar. Debes agregar esta cambio en ambos métodos, te dejo el codigo de como me quedó:

```
            public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {

                ClienteService clienteService = new ClienteService();
                Cliente cliente = clienteService.ingresarCliente();
                System.out.println("Cliente info: " + cliente.toString());
                clienteService.ingreso(cliente);
                System.out.println("luego del ingreso: " + cliente.toString());
                clienteService.retirar(cliente);
                System.out.println("luego del retiro: " + cliente.toString());
            }
        }


        public class ClienteService {
            Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
            public Cliente ingresarCliente() {
                Cliente login = new Cliente(); //el contructor vacio
                System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de cuenta");
                login.setNumeroCuenta(leer.nextInt());
                System.out.println("Ingrese su DNI");
                login.setDni(leer.nextInt());
                System.out.println("Ingrese su saldo actual");
                login.setSaldoActual(leer.nextInt());
                return login;
            }

            public void ingreso(Cliente login) {
                System.out.println("Ingresar una cantidad de dinero");
                double ingreso = leer.nextDouble();
                double suma = ingreso + login.getSaldoActual();
                login.saldoActual = suma;
                System.out.println("Se suma el dinero ingresado al Saldo actual : " + suma);
            }

            public void retirar(Cliente login) {

                System.out.println("Retirar una cantidad de dinero");
                double retiro = leer.nextDouble();

                double resta = login.getSaldoActual() - retiro;
                login.saldoActual = resta;
                System.out.println("Se resta  al Saldo actual  : " + resta);
            }
        }


        public class Cliente {
            double saldoActual;
            int dni;
            int numeroCuenta;

            public void setNumeroCuenta(int nextInt) {
                numeroCuenta = nextInt;
            }

            public void setDni(int nextInt) {
                dni = nextInt;
            }

            public void setSaldoActual(int nextInt) {
                this.saldoActual = nextInt;
            }

            public double getSaldoActual() {
                return this.saldoActual;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Cliente {" +
                        "saldoActual=" + saldoActual +
                        ", dni=" + dni +
                        ", numeroCuenta=" + numeroCuenta +
                        '}';
            }
        }
```

Se pueden mejorar varias cosas más pero espero que te ayude.

Comment: Hola al final se pudo resolver de otra manera. Me hicieron ver que en lugar de crear una variable, podria actualizar con set y despues buscar con get el SaldoActual. Igualmente me llevo tu codigo y lo pruebo en otro proyecto y me queda como referencia, asi que mil gracias por todo.